Error using polars: thread '<unnamed>' panicked at polars\polars\crates\polars-core\src\chunked_array\ops\chunkops.rs:99:17: implementation error
I am new to polars. I want to use the polars LazyFrame to apply an arbitrary number of conditions in a recursive way (just like a decision tree). After that, I need to count the amount of observations of each class that meet all the conditions. But while executing the aggregation, it appears this error:
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at C:\a\polars\polars\crates\polars-core\src\chunked_array\ops\chunkops.rs:99:17:
implementation error 

I started with an aggregation with no work on it. The return was ok.
partition.filter(pl.col('b')).group_by("target_label").agg(pl.col('b')).collect()

shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ target_label ┆ b                    │
│ ---          ┆ ---                  │
│ object       ┆ list[bool]           │
╞══════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ >50K         ┆ [true, true, … true] │
│ <=50K        ┆ [true, true, … true] │
└──────────────┴──────────────────────┘

Then, I tried to perform len, sum or count, what gives me a plan because I am using LazyFrames.
partition.filter(pl.col('b')).group_by("target_label").agg(pl.col('b').len())

naive plan: (run LazyFrame.explain(optimized=True) to see the optimized plan)

AGGREGATE
    [col("b").count()] BY [col("target_label")] FROM
  FILTER col("b") FROM

   WITH_COLUMNS:
   [[(col("a")) & (col("b"))].alias("b")]
     WITH_COLUMNS:
     [[(col("age")) < (67)].alias("a")]
       WITH_COLUMNS:
       [[(col("a")) & (col("b"))].alias("b")]
         WITH_COLUMNS:
         [[(col("age")) < (42)].alias("a")]
           WITH_COLUMNS:
           [[(col("a")) & (col("b"))].alias("b")]
             WITH_COLUMNS:
             [[(col("capital_loss")) < (3229)].alias("a")]
               WITH_COLUMNS:
               [true.alias("b")]
                DF ["age", "fnlwgt", "education_num", "capital_gain"]; PROJECT */7 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"

But when I try to collect the result of the LazyFrame, an error is thrown.
partition.filter(pl.col('b')).group_by("target_label").agg(pl.col('b').len()).collect()

thread '<unnamed>' panicked at C:\a\polars\polars\crates\polars-core\src\chunked_array\ops\chunkops.rs:99:17:
implementation error
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matorresl\Documents\genetree\test.py", line 29, in <module>
    medium_test()
  File "C:\Users\matorresl\Documents\genetree\test.py", line 22, in medium_test
    genetree.train()
  File "C:\Users\matorresl\Documents\genetree\src\genetree.py", line 94, in train
    self.tree_population = self.next_generation()
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\matorresl\Documents\genetree\src\genetree.py", line 138, in next_generation
    atree = self.crossover(a_tree, b_tree)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\matorresl\Documents\genetree\src\genetree.py", line 151, in crossover
    tree.repartition(self.data.with_columns(b=True))
  File "C:\Users\matorresl\Documents\genetree\src\tree.py", line 20, in repartition
    self.depth = self.root.repartition(partition)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\matorresl\Documents\genetree\src\node.py", line 110, in repartition
    depth_left = self.left.repartition(partition.with_columns(a=(pl.col(self.column) < self.pivot)).with_columns(b=(pl.col("a") & pl.col("b"))))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\matorresl\Documents\genetree\src\node.py", line 110, in repartition
    depth_left = self.left.repartition(partition.with_columns(a=(pl.col(self.column) < self.pivot)).with_columns(b=(pl.col("a") & pl.col("b"))))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\matorresl\Documents\genetree\src\node.py", line 110, in repartition
    depth_left = self.left.repartition(partition.with_columns(a=(pl.col(self.column) < self.pivot)).with_columns(b=(pl.col("a") & pl.col("b"))))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\matorresl\Documents\genetree\src\leaf.py", line 141, in repartition
    print(partition.filter(pl.col('b')).group_by("target_label").agg(pl.col('b').len()).collect())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\matorresl\Documents\genetree\venv\Lib\site-packages\polars\lazyframe\frame.py", line 1706, in collect
    return wrap_df(ldf.collect())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: implementation error

Am I missing something? Why is not possible to perform a len in that situation?
EDIT
The problem was related with the data used to create the LazyFrame. A full code example would be:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

data = pd.read_csv("data/amount_earning.csv")
label_np = data[['amount']].squeeze().to_numpy()
data = pl.from_pandas(data).with_columns(target_label=pl.Series(label_np)).lazy()
data = data.with_columns(b=True)
data.with_columns(a=(pl.col('age') < 25)).with_columns(b=(pl.col("a") & pl.col("b")))
data.filter(pl.col('b')).group_by("target_label").agg(pl.col('b').len()).collect()

The error is fixed by transforming label_np with .astype(str) before adding it to the LazyFrame as a column instead of using the original type object. However I can't realize which is the problem within the input data, I tested other inputs and outputs were fine, even while using the type object. I share the data used in my Github repo

A PanicException is a "bug" which may need to be reported. Are you able to provide a reproducible example i.e. code/data that creates partition? target_label has a dtype of object which may have something to do with the problem. (columns of type object are essentially "unusable" in Polars)

partition is the LazyFrame created with the function polars.from_pandas() that transforms a pandas dataframe to a polars dataframe. It is a table with string and float columns. Transforming the target_label column to string solved the problem! Thank you for the annotation.

Are you able to provide a full code example that we can run?

A full code example and the data used is shared on the EDIT section of the original question

Thanks! Your code runs for me without error on 0.20.22 - although target_label ends up as type str for me. (As an aside, is there a reason you don't use Polars to read the csv file directly?)

Nice point, no reason at all. I am moving an old code from pandas to polars to practice with this library. I still have things to change
